# Drupal 7 commerce module billing country selection based on user

Tags: php, drupal

I have a problem with Drupal 7 commerce module.

We have a country drop-down in home page and user can select any country to proceed with shopping.

Once in commerce billing section currently shows default country as CANADA. What i want to do here is based the home page country selection i have to set the same value to country drop-down in the billing section. Please anyone know how i can implement this?.

I am new to Drupal

Same type of question can find here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/120858/prepopulating-county-state-field-ajax-driven-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you get back this country selected on homepage? Maybe it appears on the url and you can use `current_path`to get it?
How do you deal with it when selected on homepage?

EDIT:
If you can access it anywhere, then you can probably use a hook_widget_form_alter in a custom module like this:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
    $element['#address']['country'] = 'US';
}
```

Replace the 'YOUR_MODULE' by your module name. And change 'US' by the ISO of the user's country. And you should also probably add a conditional statement on form_id to apply this change only on checkout form.
I hope it works!

Comment: I have the user selected country value in session and i need to display this value as billing country value in checkout page.

Comment: I have edited my previous comment with something to try for you.

Comment: Great! If it did work, can you please set this answer as the right answer. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to do up vote but i am a new user to stack overflow currently i have less reputation. Minimum 15 reputation is necessary to up vote. Any other way i can set this answer as right answer?